# How to make high quality gifs of Unity game play

Tags: unity

I've seen several Unity game play gifs, mostly on twitter. Are there any tools for making high quality gifs in Unity that are quite flexible? For example, I video recording tool that captures the game window and allows users to make gifs of portions, possible specifying the desired quality. Generally, I am looking for a tool that is quite flexible (has a lot of options for capturing gifs) and possibly game window video.

**UPDATE**

Some examples are [here](https://twitter.com/ShedworksGreg/status/861987378910679044) and [here](https://twitter.com/arranseaton/status/882411855964241922). Generally, several of the gifs that are hash-tagged madewithunity a really high quality.

Comment: Myself, I record [my](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/649089931936178176) [Unity](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/833499472495783937) [gifs](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/797640514724069376) using an external program. Do I understand correctly that you want a solution embedded in your game, so for example players could hit a "record gif" button while playing, without using an external app? We don't recommend lists of tools/libraries here, but we can give advice on implementing solutions that might entail them.

Comment: Check out [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com), it is open source. It allows you to record a preset portion of your screen.

Comment: @DMGregory I want to record gifs for the purpose of marketing my game not for players to record gameplay.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin it's for windows only, I use a Mac.

Comment: In that case, this is not a question about developing a game feature, but a request for software recommendations. [We have a dedicated StackExchange for this type of question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), and there are already [several threads there about gif capture tools for Mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=gif+mac), so I recommend that we close this question as off-topic here.